# Jquery :not selector doesn't work with style on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I am trying to make product pages for my website, unfortunately i am failing in Javascript to hide any other displays except specific page.

First of all, i wrapped up every 24 `div`'s in single `div`:

```
var lis = $(".products li");
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=24) {
  lis.slice(i, i+24)
     .wrapAll("<div class='products'></div>");
}
```

Then i gave each object of class, it's id:

```
$('.products').each(function(i, obj) {
    if (i > 0) {
       obj.id = "p" + i
    }
});
```

I have tested if it could work, and it did.

After that, i made GET request so user would choose the page.

`{{ currentpagen }}` was the value of GET request, for example, in this case, `1`.

**Then i have added the code, so all other divs would be hidden, except current page one:**

```
   $(".products:not(#p + {{ currentpagen }})").css("display", "none"); 
   $('#p' + {{ currentpagen }}).css("display", "flex");
```

and it would not work, All elements would be hidden, including one's that shouldn't be hidden by idea, for example, all element's should've been hidden in this case, except `#p1`.

---

So what could the problem be? Is there any better way to do this? Id's obviously work since i have tried changing their style, but i think it's something with `:not` selector.

**If you wonder what double curly braces are for, It is used in Django for moving variables from System to HTML, So whenever i get value of GET request, i transfer variable to HTML and then use it with double curly braces {{}}.**

Comment: What are those double curly braces in `{{ currentpagen }}` for?

Comment: +gus27 From the framework i'm using, variables are used from system to template ( HTML ) with double curly braces, So it is value of GET request, for example, when user enters the link `w.com/?browse=1`, I will transfer variable 1 from system to HTML and use it with double curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should watch out what your templating system is doing with your JavaScript code.

IMHO this could work better:

```
$(".products:not(#p" + {{ currentpagen }} + ")").css("display", "none");
```

The result should be this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it still doesn't work for some reason, why could it be so?

Comment: @ShellRox Hard to say without seeing the resulting source code of the page. Look at the HTML/JavaScript source code in the browser - and if the error is not obvious, post it in your question.

Comment: I am working on http://tonskins.com right now, There was no error regarding this code at all, and script is in the source code, view-source:http://mtonskins.pythonanywhere.com/?browse=1 script is at the end of the source code.

Comment: @ShellRox As far as I can see it from the URL, it works: p1 shows `display:flex`, the other p2 and p3 show `display:none`.

Comment: @gu27 But for some reason p1 is still hidden, maybe there's something with visibility too?

Comment: @ShellRox: Your `ul` has also `class="products"` and so it got `display:none`, too. Change the class for the `ul` element and it should work as you expect.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for finding that glitch, but now there's another problem, all elements are seen for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136663/discussion-between-shellrox-and-gus27).

Comment: @ShellRox I think the original question has been answered. For further problems please be so kind to open another question.